# Ansible: Can't loop through variable in blockinfile module

Tags: ansible, output

I am struggling to get the proper items output in this playbook:

```
---
- hosts: host1 
  gather_facts: no
  vars_files: ~./secret.txt
  tasks:
  - ngine_io.cloudstack.cs_instance_info:
      api_key: "{{ key }}"
      api_url: "{{ endpoint }}"
      api_secret: "{{ secret }}"
    register: zones
  - set_fact:
      nic_info: "{{ zones.instances|sum(attribute='nic', start=[]) | list }}"
  - set_fact:
      vlan: "{{ nic_info | selectattr('network','defined') | map(attribute='network') | list | unique | split }}"
  - name: Create file
    blockinfile:
      path: /test/vlans.txt
      block: |
        interfaces:
         - num:
           - name: {{ item.0 }}
             egr: 10000
           - name: {{ item.1 }}
             egr: 10001"
      marker: "## {mark}  {{ item }}"
    delegate_to: localhost
    with_items: "{{ vlan }}"
```

When I use this one, I get the following output on the text file:

```
## BEGIN  vlan://100

interfaces:
 - num:
   - name: v
     egr: 10000
   - name: l
     egr: 10001"
## END  vlan://100
## BEGIN  vlan://101
interfaces:
 - num:
   - name: v
     egr: 10000
   - name: l
     egr:10001"
## END  vlan://101
```

However, when I debug it by using "var: vlan.0", I get the right output:

```
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ vlan.0 }}"
```

Got this output:

```
ok: [host1] => {
    "msg": "vlan://100"
}
```

The debug of the vlan variable is:

```
"msg": [
        "vlan://100",
        "vlan://101"
    ]
```

Anyone to tell me what I am doing wrong here? Thank you.

I have also tried to run it without adding the indexes at the end, but then I get this result:

```
## BEGIN  vlan://100
"interfaces:
 - num:
   - name: 'vlan://100'
     egr: 10000
   - name: 'vlan://100'
     egr: 10001"
## END  vlan://100
## BEGIN  vlan://101
"interfaces:
 - num:
   - name: 'vlan://101'
     egr: 10000
   - name: 'vlan://101'
     egr: 10001"
## END  vlan://101
```

However, what I would like to get is:

```
## BEGIN  vlan://101
"interfaces:
 - num:
   - name: 'vlan://100'
     egr: 10000
   - name: 'vlan://101'
     egr: 10001"
## END  vlan://101
```

Comment: Your debug output prints the entire string because you are comparing different things: You are comparing `{{ vlan.0 }}` (the first item from the `vlan` list) with `{{ item.0 }}` (the first character of the string stored in `item`).

Comment: I've updated my answer to produce your desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

For the output you want, it doesn't make sense to have the task iterate over the `vlan` list, because you only want a single block. You'll need to use a template in the block content instead, like this:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    vlan:
      - vlan://100
      - vlan://101

  tasks:
    - name: Create file
      blockinfile:
        path: vlans.txt
        block: |
          interfaces:
            - num:
              {% for item in vlan -%}
              - name: {{ item }}
                egr: {{ (item.split('//')[1])|int + 9900 }}
              {% endfor %}
        marker: "## {mark} vlans"
      delegate_to: localhost
```

This will result in:

```
## BEGIN vlans
interfaces:
  - num:
    - name: vlan://100
      egr: 10000
    - name: vlan://101
      egr: 10001
    
## END vlans
```

I had to add a slightly funky calculation there to get the `egr` value, since you seemed to expect that to change along with the vlan.

---

### Original answer

The `vlan` variable is, based on your debug output, a list of strings:

```
"msg": [
        "vlan://100",
        "vlan://101"
    ]
```

That means that when you iterate over `vlan` in your `blockinfile` task, `item` will take the value of successive items from the `vlan` list.

In other words, during the first iteration, `item` will be `vlan://100`. Since we know this, it should be no surprise that `{{ item.0 }}` results in `v`: we've asked for the first character of the string `vlan://100`.

That means we probably want:

```
  - name: Create file
    blockinfile:
      path: /test/vlans.txt
      block: |
        interfaces:
         - num:
           - name: {{ item }}
             egr: 10000
           - name: {{ item }}
             egr: 10001"
      marker: "## {mark}  {{ item }}"
    delegate_to: localhost
    with_items: "{{ vlan }}"
```

But it sounds like you've already realized the correct solution:

> I have also tried to run it without adding the indexes at the end, but then I get the expected result...

Comment: Hi, sorry I have edited my question, as it was an expected result but not the one I wanted.  I would like to convert each string into a single list so I could loop over each of them.
What I don't understand is that when I debug vlan.0, I get the proper result (vlan:100), and not the first letter....

Comment: I think you have an error in your `debug` task, but since you have posted neither the task nor the corresponding output it's hard to tell. Maybe update your question to include that information?

Comment: Right I have edited the question, I get the right vlan100 when I'm debugging with "vlan.0", and that's making me very confused.

Comment: Glad to help! If this has resolved your question, consider clicking the checkmark to the left of this answer to mark it as accepted.